# IB API Python saving variable and more problems

Tags: python, api

I've followed the IB manual for TWS API method to extract some data. a few problems rise as I try to save the values in a variable to be used later.

1. I try to save some values (ask price, day low, day high etc...)if I print it in the 'class' it works but after that it "forgets" it,  and as I want to print it after all the process of the receiving data, it remains 0(as it was set at the start of the code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time
a=0
b=0
c=0
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 2 and reqId == 1:#returns ASK price
            a = float(price)
            print(a)
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)
        if tickType == 7 and reqId == 1:# returns Low price
            b = float(price)
            print(b)
            print('Low = ', price)
        if tickType == 6 and reqId == 1:# returns High price
            c=float(price)
            print(c)
            print('High = ', price)
def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)


#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#Create contract object
fut_contract = Contract()
fut_contract.symbol = 'MESZ1' #MES DEC'21
fut_contract.secType = 'FUT'
fut_contract.exchange = 'GLOBEX'
fut_contract.currency = 'USD'
fut_contract.tradingClass = 'MES'
fut_contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '202112'

#Request Market Data
app.reqMarketDataType(2) #1-Real 2-Frozen 3-Delayed 4-Fro & Del
app.reqMktData(1, fut_contract, "", False, False, [])


time.sleep(10) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
print(a,b,c)
app.disconnect()
```

2. I made another code to extract the cash balance from the account. and weirdly it only works when I add th contract type I want, but I don't really use it

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

import threading
import time
a=0
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        self.reqAccountSummary(9002, "All", "$LEDGER:USD")
    def accountSummary(self, reqId: int, account: str, tag: str, value: str, currency: str):
        super().accountSummary(reqId, account, tag, value, currency)
        if tag == 'CashBalance':
            print("AccountSummary", "Tag: ", tag, "Value:", value, "Currency:",currency)
            return value


def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

#Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(1) #Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

#***THIS IS THE PART THAT NEED TO BE INSIDE THE CODE FOR IT TO WORK AND I DONT KNOW WHY????!!!***

fut_contract = Contract()
fut_contract.symbol = 'MESZ1' #MES DEC'21
fut_contract.secType = 'FUT'
fut_contract.exchange = 'GLOBEX'
fut_contract.currency = 'USD'
fut_contract.tradingClass = 'MES'
fut_contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = '202112'

#Request Market Data
app.reqMarketDataType(2) #1-Real 2-Frozen 3-Delayed 4-Fro & Del
app.reqMktData(1, fut_contract, "", False, False, [])

#***THIS IS THE END OF THE PART....***

time.sleep(10) #Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data

app.disconnect()
```

Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: Please clarify your statement " try to save some values (ask price, day low, day high etc...)if I print it in the 'class' it works but after that it "forgets" it, and as I want to print it after all the process of the receiving data, it remains 0(as it was set at the start of the code:"  Which it do you want ton print?  Which it forgets?  and which it remains 0?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! The parameter a, b, c... those are the value that returns and if i print it in the def, it is good. but after it finish extractin the data, it is like this parameters never got the value and return as 0. I hope i was understandable this time. Thanks!